# Скрыть блок div через css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть несколько дивов, формируются через php, в итоге получается такой код:

```
<div id="order1"> Текст для показа
<div id="order_item1">Текст который надо скрыть</div>
</div>

<div id="order2"> Текст для показа
<div id="order_item2">Текст который надо скрыть</div>
</div>
```

Хочется, чтобы по умолчанию дивы `order_item` были скрыты, а при нажатии на ссылку "Текст для показа" отображались.
Хочется это все сделать на css, знаю что там есть атрибут `display:none`, но как сделать ссылку, при нажатии которой, свойство бы менялось, а тем более когда несколько блоков, не могу понять.

Comment: С помощью `css` ? Почему не `JS`?

Comment: можно и с помощью js, но с ним я пока не дружу

Comment: Как Вы понимаете, в **css** нету обработчика нажатия на блок.   
По-этому, Вы вынуждены использовать **js**.

Answer (score 5):

Кстати, если использовать `display:none` то плавности в появление и исчезновении не будет.

```js
/*хватаем элемент order*/
const order = document.getElementsByClassName('order');
/*хватаем элемент order_item*/
const order_item = document.getElementsByClassName('order_item');

/* и тут прокручиваем в цикле order*/
for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
  // и тут событие срабатывает  которое добавляет и удаляет класс
  order[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    order_item[i].classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.order_item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.order_item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="order" id="order1"> Текст для показа
  <div class="order_item" id="order_item1">Текст который надо скрыть</div>
</div>

<div class="order" id="order2"> Текст для показа
  <div class="order_item" id="order_item2">Текст который надо скрыть</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример с двумя блоками без JS

```css
/* скрываем чекбоксы и блоки с содержанием */

.hide,
.hide+label~div {
  display: none;
}


/* вид текста label */

.hide+label,
.hide:checked+label {
  padding: 0;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted green;
}


/* вид текста label при активном переключателе */

.hide:checked+label {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 0;
}


/* когда чекбокс активен показываем блоки с содержанием  */

.hide:checked+label+div {
  display: block;
  background: #efefef;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #7d8e8f;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="hide" id="hd-1" type="checkbox">
<label for="hd-1">Нажмите здесь, чтобы открыть!</label>
<div>Скрытое содержание......</div>
<input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
<label for="hd-2">Нажмите здесь, чтобы прочитать больше!</label>
<div>Скрытое содержание...</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, что напомнили об этом решении (+) Думаю многим будет полезно.